# Upgrading to Android Studio 0.8

Tags: android, android-studio, upgrade

Hi I used to have  Android Studio 0.5 and it was working fine.

how I upgraded to 0.8 and got this

- When I open my project, I do not see project files and I get failed to find target android-19

anyone know how to fix this?

thanks

[image]

Comment: You should probably get android 19 SDK

Comment: this is upgrade, i already have it from the previous version

Comment: Your IDE says otherwise.

Comment: i will install and see, thanks